# xsd ignore order of elements and maxOccurs unbound

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want my xsd-file to match a xml tag within elements that can occure unbounded and in different order. Thats a example xml:

```
            <Root>                
                <List Name="ListNode">
                    <FirstNode Name="Test" />
                    <SecondNode />
                    <SecondNode />
                    <FirstNode Name="Test2" />
                    <ThirdNode />
                </List>

                <FirstNode Name="Test3" />
                <ThirdNode />
            </Root>
```

Thats my xsd-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="Root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="List">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:all>
                            <xsd:element name="FirstNode" >
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="SecondNode" />
                            <xsd:element name="ThirdNode" />
                        </xsd:all>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="FirstNode" >
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="SecondNode" />
                <xsd:element name="ThirdNode" />
            </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I think xsd:all is not the rigth tag. Any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="FirstNode"/>
  <xsd:element name="SecondNode" />
  <xsd:element name="ThirdNode" />
</xs:choice>
```